# Confused by calculation

Tags: c#, vb6, calculator

I am porting an application from VB6 to C#. I have found one calculation in particular that is causing me an issue. It basically boils down to

```
opperandA *.01 / opperandB
```

My concrete example is:

```
1 * .01 / 12
```

In VB6  (and Windows Calculator) I get 8.3333333333e-4.

However, in C# (and every other Calculator) I get .00083333.

The second number makes sense to me, but I have to replication the first result and I want to understand it, so why does VB6 and Windows calculator produce an odd result?

Comment: Hint: [*scientific notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). Use `result.ToString("R")` to convert the float/double to a string without this notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

8.3333333333e-4 is the same as 0.00083333.  It equates to:

```
8.3333333333 * 10^-4
= 8.3333333333 times ( ten to the power of -4 )
= 8.3333333333 * 0.0001
= 0.00083333333
N.b. After rounding
```

The e stands for exponent and the relevant Wikipedia article is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation

Comment: It is close to the same thing however 8.3333333333e-4 is more accurate than .00083333. It's possible that VB defaults to floats. try opperandA *.01f / opperandB